# Set method in a simple c++ class file returning strange values

Tags: c++

I am having trouble using a set function in a class file. So far I have the following. I am trying to write a quadratic class that has three private data members and can calculate both the value of a quadratic and the number of real roots in the quadratic. I'm not stuck on the math part as much as I am getting the set methods to not give me weird values. When I test using main, the values for a, b, and c are numbers that I didn't input when I created the object.

Quadratic.hpp

```
#ifndef QUADRATIC_HPP
#define QUADRATIC_HPP

class Quadratic
{
 private:
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;

 public:    
  Quadratic();
  Quadratic(double, double, double);

  void setA(double);
  void setB(double);
  void setC(double);

  double getA();
  double getB();
  double getC();

  double valueFor(double);    
  int numRealRoots();
};
#endif
```

Quadratic.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream> 

Quadratic::Quadratic()
{
  setA(1.0);
  setB(1.0);
  setC(1.0);    
}

Quadratic::Quadratic(double A, double B, double C)
{
  a = A;
  b = B;
  c = C;
}

void Quadratic::setA(double A)
{
  a = A;
}

void Quadratic::setB(double B)
{
  a = B;
}

void Quadratic::setC(double C)
{
  c = C;
}

double Quadratic::getA()
{
  return a;
}

double Quadratic::getB()
{
  return b;
}

double Quadratic::getC()
{
  return c;
}

double Quadratic::valueFor(double x)
{
  return (a*(pow(x,2)) + b*x + c);
}

int Quadratic:: numRealRoots()
{
  double discriminant = pow(b,2) - (4*a*c);
  double epsilon = 0.00001;

  int realRoots;
  if (discriminant <= epsilon && discriminant > 0)        
     realRoots = 1;
  else if (discriminant > epsilon)
    realRoots = 2;
  else
    realRoots = 0;

return realRoots;
}
```

Comment: How to make code unreadable - too much vertical whitespace.

Comment: @Neil the only problem function is `numRealRoots` the rest is easily readable

Comment: Sorry Neil. I'll be sure to work on that next time I post.

Comment: [OT]: Your getter should be `const`, and you don't handle degenerate case: `a == 0`.

Comment: Probably the problem is in the main test function you applied. Unfortunately, you haven't posted it.

Comment: Prefer to use {meaningful} variable names in your declarations.  The order and name should match the definition.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: `a`, `b`, `c` are regular names to express `a.x² + b.x + c`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `setB` method is wrong - it updates `a` instead of `b`:

```
void Quadratic::setB(double B)
{
    b = B; // Was "a = B;" in the original code
}
```

Comment: Also - it's bad practice to use direct assignment in constructor. It's better use setters instead: `Quadratic::Quadratic(double A, double B, double C)
{
  setA(A);
  setB(B);
  setC(C);
}`.

Comment: @BorLaze: It is better to use initializer list. `Quadratic::Quadratic(double A, double B, double C) : a(A), b(B), c(C) {}`.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Can't believe I didn't catch that. Are the set methods used correctly other than that mistake?

Comment: @T.Saut basically looks fine to me, but check out the other comment here wrt implementing the constructor